# MySQL query across entire database

Tags: mysql

Database with 17 tables. 
base holds:  `id`, `dog`, `owner`, `regno`
15 tables hold `tablename_regno` and `numerous` which have `INT` type.
The last table holds `tablename_regno` and three variable fields

I would like to select the `Dog`, `owner` and `regno` from `Table1` and all `fields >0` in the 15 tables and any `variable fields <> 'xxxx'` in table 17

Is this possible without listing all field names etc?
Can I somehow incorporate `SELECT from Information_schema.columns`

Note:   `regno = tablename_regno` 
---------------------Clarification------------

```
CREATE TABLE base(
id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
regno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
owner VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
dog VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE conf(
id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
conf_regno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
conf_CH_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
conf_CH_V INT(2) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
conf_GCH_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
conf_SN_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
conf_SN_V INT(2) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

I have 15 tables similar to the one above

CREATE TABLE versatile(
id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
v_regno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
v_VL_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
v_VLA_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
v_VLX_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx'
);
```

I need dog, owner and regno from base, and all the INT fields >0 in the 15 tables, as well as any fields in versatile not_equal to xxxx.

Hope that helps

Comment: U not required join here?

Comment: @devpro Sorry, do not understand your comment nor your down rating?

Comment: Question is unclear. Are the 15 tables you are trying to span really one dataset broken into 15 parts? You can select only the appropriate field names in the select statement. ie `select t1.field_1, t2.field_2, ... from t1, t2`

Comment: No I didnt the down vote.. I am here for help u not for vote or unvote friend

Comment: Clarifying with 3 table example.

Comment: Well just give a example with 3 or 4 tables and also share the fields names of all tables and share yur expacted result

Comment: You are asking a very weird question probably because of lack of experience, but I guess if you start with the motivation or idea you want to implement there will definitely be a way to go with couple of tables with a simplified answer

Comment: @sharonbetts: now its look good, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is not possible without "dynamic" sql; which is a succinct way of saying "using knowledge of the schema and/or data from information_schema to construct a query during execution" (normally done "in code" or a stored procedure).

A query must explicitly define which fields (or all with `*`, or `tablename.*`) are returned and which tables are used.

Edit: One sort of workaround would be to create a `VIEW` that is the `UNION` of those 15 tables, and join the "base" table to that instead.

*The need for this task indicates that those 15 tables probably should have been one table, with an additional field to categorize rows into 15 different "groups".*

Comment: Thank you @Uueerdo - I will work on the View concept.  Interestingly my first design had all the 15 tables as one.

Comment: @sharonbetts Yes, using a stored procedure, a query string could be assembled and executed using `PREPARE`; but the query would still need manually constructed in the procedure's code. There is nothing like `SELECT * FROM a JOIN b (where b.tablename like 'something%') ON a.id = b.a_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.regno,b.owner,b.dog,c.*,v.*
FROM base b
INNER JOIN conf c ON c.conf_regno = b.regno
INNER JOIN versatile v ON c.v_regno = b.regno
WHERE 
(
c.conf_CH_V > 0 AND c.conf_SN_V > 0
) 
AND 
(
c.conf_regno != '' AND c.conf_CH_Y != '' AND c.conf_GCH_Y != '' 
AND c.conf_SN_Y != '' AND v.v_regno != '' AND v.v_VL_Y != '' 
AND v.v_VLA_Y != '' AND v.v_VLX_Y != ''
)
```

> **Note that:** this solution is only for three tables those you have
>   mentioned in question. You can add more tables as like same.